# Accessing web page with CasperJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I am able to access Google to get a page title:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
casper.start('http://google.com', function() {
    this.echo(this.getTitle());
})
casper.run();
// "Google"
```

But for some reason I'm not able to get the iTunes Connect page:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
casper.start('https://itunesconnect.apple.com', function() {
    this.echo(this.getTitle());
})
// Undefined
```

How would I successfully request the above page?

Here is what I currently get:

```
[info] [phantom] Starting...
[info] [phantom] Running suite: 2 steps
[debug] [phantom] opening url: https://itunesconnect.apple.com/, HTTP GET
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://itunesconnect.apple.com/, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=true
[warning] [phantom] Loading resource failed with status=fail: https://itunesconnect.apple.com/
[debug] [phantom] Successfully injected Casper client-side utilities
[object Casper], currently at about:blank
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 2/2: done in 66ms.
[info] [phantom] Done 2 steps in 86ms
```

Comment: What version of PhantomJS do you use? Please register to the `resource.error`, `page.error`, `remote.message` and `casper.page.onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf)). Maybe there are errors.

Comment: @ArtjomB. how would I apply the above inside the `start()` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify ssl when running the script:

```
casperjs --ssl-protocol=tlsv1 script.js
```